# Method what sets the flag according to the property value

Tags: c#, properties

I have a Java Webservice and I'm implementing a client in .Net. Now I've got a problem similar to this: [Java Webservice and .NET client dropping DateTime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677754/java-webservice-and-net-client-dropping-datetime-objects).
I know how to set a flag when I have a value in property, but I need a method which will set that flag automatically. For example (I removed the attributes to increase readability):

```
public class MyClass
{
    private System.DateTime endDateTimeField;

    private bool endDateTimeFieldSpecified;

    private System.DateTime startDateTimeField;

    private System.DateTime firstDriverStartField;

    private System.DateTime firstDriverEndField;

    private System.DateTime secondDriverStartField;

    private bool secondDriverStartFieldSpecified;

    private System.DateTime secondDriverEndField;

    private bool secondDriverEndFieldSpecified;

    private string exciseNumberField;

    private double gasCounterEndField;

    private double gasCounterStartField;

    private string idField;

    private double mileageStartField;

    private double mileageEndField;

    private obtcStatus obtcStatusField;

    private string secondDriverField;
}
```

All property with simple type have automatically add "MyProperty" + Specified.
I need a method that checks for an entire object or if it has MyProperty / MyPropertySpecified pairs and if MyProperty is set to a value other than null, then sets the MyPropertySpecified flag to true.

Edit:
My problem concerns fields:
private System.DateTime endDateTimeField;
private bool endDateTimeFieldSpecified;

private System.DateTime secondDriverStartField;
private bool secondDriverStartFieldSpecified;

private System.DateTime secondDriverEndField;
private bool secondDriverEndFieldSpecified;

Probably i can use something like this:

public static void SetProperyValue(object obj)
        {
            IEnumerable props = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "endDateTimeField" || x.Name == "endDateTimeFieldSpecified");

```
        if (props?.Count() == 2 &&
            props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "endDateTimeField").GetValue(obj) != null)            
            props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "endDateTimeFieldSpecified").SetValue(obj, true);            
    }
```

But i don't want use property name on rigid

Comment: I dont understand if you need a way without knowing the property names, then you could only use reflection.

Comment: @Newer: Could you answer my question? Do you know the names of the properties at compile time? Otherwise it's difficult to find the type of the related value-property. Because there is no `Int`-type(it's `System.Int32`). So you also need a dictionary to translate your abbreviated names to the real .NET types.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes i know a name of all property, becouse it is automatically generate when you add Service References to C# in VS. Poproepty not change until i not change interface (WSDL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found solution:

```
    public static void SetPropertyValues(object obj)
    {
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Specified"));
        List<Tuple<string, string>> propertyList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        foreach (var item in props)            
            propertyList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(item.Name.Replace("Specified",""), item.Name));            

        foreach (var item in propertyList)           
            setPropertyValue(obj, item.Item1, item.Item2);            
    }

    private static void setPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName, string flagName)
    {
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.Name == propertyName || x.Name == flagName);

        var propValue = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName).GetValue(obj);

        if (props?.Count() == 2 && propValue != null && checkMinValue(propValue.GetType(), propValue))
            props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == flagName).SetValue(obj, true);
    }

    private static bool checkMinValue(Type type, object obj )
    {
        if (type.Name == "DateTime")
            return Convert.ToDateTime(obj) != DateTime.MinValue;
        if (type.Name == "Double")
            return Convert.ToDouble(obj) != double.MinValue;
        if (type.Name == "Int32")
            return Convert.ToInt32(obj) != Int32.MinValue;

        return true;
    }
```

Yup i know it can be better write but for now i think it will be work:)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you exactly want (please specify your question better), but I guess something like this (Note that you have to make your int and DateTime nullable if you want to check them for null, because they both are structs):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int? MyInt { get; set; }
    public bool MyIntSpecified => MyInt.HasValue;
    public DateTime? MyDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool MyDateTimeSpecified => MyDateTime.HasValue;
}
```